# How do I update table A while adding rows on table B?

Tags: sql

My table A is about item records in the stock and table B is about purchase record.
https://ibb.co/KyJzXZm

When customer makes a purchase, table B will be updated, showing the purchase_id, item_id and item_quantity. At the same time, the same item in table A will be updated and reduced by the quantity in table B. Therefore the item quantity in table A should be (4 - 3 = 1). Table A should be updated whenever I update table B. Does anyone know how to do it? Thank you!!!

Comment: you should show your approach and trials.

Answer (score 0):

I have figured out a way to do so.
Just create a log table for table B. Then create a trigger on "After Insert"
on table B, update the log table. By doing so, you will get a New.item_id and New.item_quantity. Then create another trigger, "After Insert" on table B, then update table A,
SET item_quantity = item_quantity - New.item_quantity WHERE item_id = New.item_id
Below is my original code,

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER purchase_log_insert
AFTER INSERT ON purchase
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN 
    INSERT INTO log_purchase (action, purchase_id_new, item_id_new, purchase_quantity_new, timestamp)
    VALUES ('insert', NEW.purchase_id, NEW.item_id, NEW.purchase_quantity, NOW());
END; //
DELIMITER ;

DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER change_item
AFTER INSERT ON purchase
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
    UPDATE item
    SET item_quantity = item_quantity - NEW.purchase_quantity WHERE item_id = NEW.item_id;
END; //
DELIMITER ;
```